# Android Google Play Service duplicated

Tags: android, google-play-services

Anyone has idea about this Error genre,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest
>   merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value
>   value=(@integer/google_play_services_version) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-66  is also present at
>   [io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.0.11] AndroidManifest.xml:31:13-36
>   value=(6587000)   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>    element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-18:69 to override

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your manifest under application tag add tools replace tag, Like this application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:value"
Then try to compile and run...

Comment: @user3619413 Thnx..pls accept the answer if it worked, it could help other people with same problem. Happy android coding :)